# Advanced JPA Query/Subquery

Tags: jpa, jpql

Given the following code:

```
final Class<T> cl = (Class<T>) example.getClass();
final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(cl);
final Root<T> r = cq.from(cl);
TypedQuery<T> query = em.createQuery(cq);
```

I must replace the `cq.from(c1)` to a subquery, for example `cq.from('SELECT * FROM TABLE(PROCEDURE_NAME(?))')`.

If I put `c1`, there are no results.

Comment: In the original code there is `cl` (lower case L), not `c1` (number one).

Comment: Sorry, if i put cl, there are no results. I´ve written wrong here